# Not Able to Stop Progress Bar on Certain Point

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48jdt1qt/1/)**

Using jQuery progressbar.js plugin I am not able to stop the progress bar at any certain point. Unfortunately the plugin api didn't explain how to do this but I tried to do it on my own by declaring a target variable which is storing progress value.

```
 target = bar.value();
```

Then I tried to stop the progress by applying an if condition like this

```
if ((target * 100).toFixed(0) == 60) {
    circle.stop();
}
```

but this is not stopping the progress bar on 60! I tried to use this based on the   `circle.stop();` function (If you click on stop button it stops the progess and alerts the value of bar (target) but the if stattement not working!

```
var target;
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#container', {
    color: '#FCB03C',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    trailWidth: 1,
    duration: 1500,
    bar: 60,
    text: {
        value: '0'
    },
    step: function (state, bar) {
        bar.setText((bar.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
        target = bar.value();
    }
});

circle.animate(1, function () {
    circle.animate();
})


if ((target * 100).toFixed(0) == 60) {
    circle.stop();
}


$('#stop').on('click', function () {
    circle.stop();
    alert((target * 100).toFixed(0));
});
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your demo isn't working is you're checking the target only once, when it's just declared, without any value. `(undefined * 100).toFixed(0) == "NaN"`. Since javascript isn't reactive by default, you have to check the condition every time `target` updates. The `step` function is perfect for this, since it's called every time value changes. To fix the error, move:

```
if ((target * 100).toFixed(0) == 60) {
    circle.stop();
}
```

inside `step` function:

```
step: function (state, bar) {
    bar.setText((bar.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
    target = bar.value();
    if ((target * 100).toFixed(0) == 60) {
        circle.stop();
    }
}
```

[Fixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/48jdt1qt/2/).

Comment: Thanks Maremp, I already tried this but was getting error must be a typo or something else on my code! Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. If you're interested in details, I've updated the answer to add a bit more description.

Comment: Sure thanks alot , by the way I have to wait 10 mins to accept your answer